# I Want Users Browse The File, But It Affects to My Script

Tags: matlab, variables, matlab-uitable

I'm doing with MATLAB.

I have a file named 'cobat'. Cobat is a *txt file, tab delimited, consisted of 3 coloumns, so it's a table. I load it manually into this script:

I want users browse their own file. How can I do it? Is this code correct:

```
[filename pathname] = uigetfile(('.txt'), 'Browse Your File')
```

Here are my problems:

1. I think it is only for text file, not tab delimited (table). I think I have to use uitable, but I don't understand how to implement it, because the file (cobat) should be loaded.
2. And, if it has been implemented, I can't write 'cobat' in my script, like this:

`[g c] = kmeans(cobat,k,'dist','SqEuclidean'); y = [cobat g]`

Then I have to change 'cobat' to what name?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. After locating the file you need to [`load`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html) it:

```
load([pathname filesep filename])
```

If file name is `cobat` (or `cobat.txt`), it will create a matrix called `cobat` in the workspace with the content of the file.

Comment: Thank you. But what about this line? `[g c] = kmeans(cobat,k,'dist','SqEuclidean'); y = [cobat g]` There is 'cobat', I have to change it to what?

Comment: You don't need to change it, it should work now that the variable `cobat` exists.

Comment: Thank you, Simon. But how if I load another file with another name? Is it okay to write 'cobat'?

Comment: You should read the manual page that I linked. You can use `load` to load the content of a file into a variable. For instance, `x = load('foo.txt');` loads the content of `foo.txt` into the variable `x`.